# Read and transfer a binary file through socket

Tags: .net, file, visual-c++, binary

I've got a problem to read a binary file properly.
A simple example is to properly read a file which contains only the char permile (‰).

I tried many solutions:

with a binary reader:

```
System::IO::FileStream^ stream = gcnew System::IO::FileStream(path, System::IO::FileMode::Open);
System::IO::BinaryReader^ reader = gcnew System::IO::BinaryReader(stream, System::Text::Encoding::UTF32);
array<Byte>^ bytes = gcnew array<Byte>(128);
    
do
{
    bytes[i] = reader->ReadByte(); // the Byte in bytes[i] is not good
    // ... some other code
} while (//condition);
```

I tried directly with a StreamReader:

```
System::IO::StreamReader^ stream2 = gcnew System::IO::StreamReader(path);
array<wchar_t>^ bytes = gcnew arra<Byte>(128);

do
{
    stream2->Read(bytes, 0, 128); // the Byte in bytes[i] is not good
    // ... some other code
} while (//condition);
```

I never succeeded to correctly read my permile char.

I tried to change the encoding method (ASCII, UTF-8, UTF32, etc...)

Anybody have an idea?

Thanks a lot

Comment: When you write a file with "‰" what bytes do you expect in it? In other words, which character encoding are you using to write the file? After you write it, you can consider all files to be binary but you can't consider all files to be text. So, it is quite unclear what your goal is. Please [edit] to clarify.

Comment: @Tom Bloget : Hi, thanks for your answer. I'm sorry but I don't understand your question. I want to open the file as binary. My final goal is to transfer binary files through sockets like pictures for exemple.

Comment: First, if the file isn't huge, `File::ReadAllBytes` (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.readallbytes(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=cpp#code-snippet-1) is the simplest way.

Comment: I think you are confusing the issue with your test data.  "[‰](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/2030/index.htm)" could be 0xE2 0x80 0xB0 or 0x20 0x30 or 0x30 0x20 or 0x00 0x00 0x20 0x30 or 0x30 0x20 0x00 0x00 or any of the preceeding with a BOM. Or, 0x89 or ….